# Dot after thechapter in the ToC, but not in the body text?

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, numbering

How do I add a dot after `thechapter` in the ToC, but have no dot after `thechapter` in the body?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% toc:
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
[1.5em]{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
{\contentslabel{1.5em}\hspace*{0em}}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\chapter{bar}
\chapter{baz}

\end{document}
```

I tried to define `thechapter` with dot before the ToC, and then redifine it with no dot after the ToC, but it doesn't work:

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}.}
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
```

**Edit**:

Thanks to egreg, the solution is:

```
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
```

I also had to:

```
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\theproblem{\thechapter.\arabic{problem}.}
```

in order to have dot in the name of the figures, problems, etc.

Comment: You mention that you need to redefine the numbering systems for the `equation`, `figure`, etc environments in order for them to have a dot in the extended numbering form. It's surprising you need to do so, as the `book` document class should impose this numbering system by default. Are you maybe using another document class?

Comment: @Mico: I'm using `scrbook`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying which document class you use. The `scrbook` class also numbers equations, figures, etc *automatically* within each chapter. The `\renewcommand` directives you list in your posting should thus not be necessary.

Comment: @Mico: thanks for posting the solution with tocloft. I [have complex setup](https://github.com/bk322/bk_TeXs/blob/master/sty/bk-XeLaTeXs-MISiS-problems-book-ru.sty) and dot after chapter was missing in, for example, list of figures and list of problems. Also in some other places. Probably I did something wrong. I'm sure next time I'll do it better.

Comment: Thanks for providing this additional piece of information. Note that your method for redefining the composite numbering of equations, figures, etc may fail since there's no guarantee that the equation/figure/problem numbers will be reset (to `0`) every time a new `\chapter` command is encountered. Since it appears that you're using the `amsmath` package, you could issue commands such as `\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}`, etc to achieve a robust numbering system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the end of section 6.2 in the documentation of `titlesec`/`titletoc` you find the solution:

```
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
```

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fontspec} % enagles loading of OpenType fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia} % support for languages

% fonts:
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} % without this XeLaTeX won't turn "--" into dashes
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

% toc:
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]
  {\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
  {\contentslabel{1.5em}\hspace*{0em}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{foo}
\chapter{bar}
\chapter{baz}

\end{document}
```

If you want to use the period only for chapters and not for sections, you can do it differently

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.5em]
  {\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
  {\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.\hfill]{1.5em}\hspace*{0em}}
  {}
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone prefers using the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package rather than the `titletoc` package: To achieve the OP's objective, it suffices to load the `tocloft` package and issue the command

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
```

in the preamble. Separately, if you wanted a set of "dot leaders" between the chapter name and the associated page number, you can get LaTeX to do so by issuing the command

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```

The following MWE illustrates the effect of `\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ABC}
\chapter{DEF}
\end{document}
```

[image]